# Is $\mathbb{C}(x)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$? (As fields)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an isomorphism between the field $\mathbb{C}$ (the complex field) and the field $\mathbb{C(x)}$?

Comment: *Hint*: Is $\mathbb C(x)$ algebraically closed?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: is $x$ a square in $\mathbb C(x)$?

Comment: This is a nice argument,  way simpler than I would have considered +1